# Is there a known example of a voting system that does not satify the dictator fairness criterion but does satisfy the others?

Tags: game-theory, decision-theory, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem), Arrow's impossibility theorem states that no rank-order electoral system can be designed that always satisfies these three "fairness" criteria:

1. If every voter prefers alternative X over alternative Y, then the
   group prefers X over Y.
2. If every voter's preference between X and Y remains unchanged, then the group's preference between X and Y will also remain
   unchanged (even if voters' preferences between other pairs like X
   and Z, Y and Z, or Z and W change).
3. There is no "dictator": no single voter possesses the power to always determine the group's preference.

Is there a known example of a voting system which fulfills the first two criteria, (and therefore fails to fulfill the third,) for which an example set of votes can be shown to contain one or more dictators?

Edit:

Voting systems that literally, directly, choose a dictator are not satisfying to me regarding this question. However if it can be demonstrated that directly choosing a dictator is the only way a voting system can fail the third criteria, then I would find that satisfying.

Comment: Does a dictator choice function satisfy what you are asking? It's the social choice function that always goes with a fixed individuals top preference. (It satisfies the first two properties.)

Comment: The theorem tells you that any system that satisfies the first two conditions necessarily fails the third. You’re really asking for some way to disguise a dictatorial system — one in which the preferences of some particular voter $v$ determine the group’s collective preference schedule — so that at first blush its nature is not evident. The system itself is still just going to choose $v$’s preference schedule; any other apparent mechanics are just obfuscation that must cancel out. (By the way, it is by definition impossible to have more than one dictator.)

Comment: Also, you might be amused to note that there are randomized social choice functions that beat this theorem. For instance, take a uniformly random person, and declare them to be the dictator.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott People talk about Arrow's impossibility theorem as if it means there's no way to make a fair voting system, even if you try. I'm interested in voting systems that fail regarding the third criteria even if the system is an attempt to be fair. Are you saying that failing the third criteria never happens except as the result of a rule that directly specifies a dictator?

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Wouldn't randomness in the procedure automatically invalidate the second criteria? For instance if we have 3 voters that prefer X over Y and a fourth that prefers Y over X, and we hold "votes" under that scheme over and over until the voter that prefers Y is picked, doesn't that constitute the chosen group's preference changing even though no voter has changed their preference?

Comment: @Ryan1729 Arrow's theorem only applies to ordinal voting systems, so there are many that evade it

Comment: @Ryan1729: I’m saying that if you have an ordinal voting system that satisfies the first two conditions, then one voter is a dictator. That’s what the theorem says. Conceivably the rule may be designed in such a way that this fact is not immediately obvious, but that’s just obfuscation, intentional or otherwise.

Comment: To add to what Brian is saying: A common criticism of Arrow's theorem is just that it reveals that ordinal preferences are insufficient information to recover good aggregate preference; this is an argument that I think Amartya Sen makes somewhere. Regarding randomized voting: You'd have to reformulate the second condition as the probability distribution over preferences not changing.

Answer (score 1):

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830347/can-we-make-a-voting-system-where-it-is-cryptographically-hard-to-find-a-dictato) and reading further, I have come to the conclusion that it is the case that if a voting system meets the first two criteria, then the voting system will be doing some form of directly choosing the dictator.

In particular, I found working through [this proof of Arrow's Impossibility theorem](https://svasey.com/academic-homepage-may-2020/141a-fall-2018/arrow.pdf) [(Wayback link)](http://web.archive.org/web/20240405155520/https://svasey.com/academic-homepage-may-2020/141a-fall-2018/arrow.pdf) finally convinced me.

Answer (score 1):

To get a better real-world feel for how the "dictator" in Arrow's impossibility theorem actually "dictates", imagine a hypothetical country that has some kind of "Supreme Court", with nine judges on it. This court regularly rules on legal cases of great political significance to the two major political parties, the "Red Party" and the "Blue Party". While in theory the judges are impartial, in practice, eight of the nine judges have well-known partisan alignments--four "Red", four "Blue"--and their votes on any given case are completely predictable: all the Reds vote the same way, and all the Blues vote the same way. There is only one judge who does not align with a particular party and whose preferences in any given case are unpredictable; they are considered the "swing judge".

Let's call the three conditions (I), (II), and (III) in OP's post "unanimity", "independence of irrelevant alternatives", and "non-dictatorship". I make two claims about how this voting system works *in practice:*

**Claim 1: This system satisfies the conditions on unanimity and independence of irrelevant alternatives.** In principle these conditions *could* be violated in this setting; but in practice they never are, because all four Red judges have identical preferences and vote identically, and so do all four Blue judges, so no "strategic voting" ever occurs.

**Claim 2: The swing judge is the "dictator."** Because the rest of the Court is evenly balanced, the swing judge's decision is also the Court's decision, in every case. Even though in principle, the swing judge's vote doesn't count more or less than anyone else's, in practice, their vote is always the decisive one.